# Assembly Beginner: Set a variable equal to the number of values in DCD?

Tags: variables, assembly, thumb

So I am learning assembly and I have written a program to sum values I define in 'data_type'.

Atm I am having to manually set variable 'num' equal to the quantity of values in 'data_type' to ensure the loop sums them all.

I was wondering whether there is a better way of doing this?

Or if there is a way to declare variable 'num' dynamically to assume the quantity of values in 'data_type'?

Thanks in advance!

```
AREA Sum loop, CODE, READONLY
 ENTRY
 num EQU 5
 Reset_Handler
 LDR r1, =data_values
 MOV r5,#num     
 loop   
 LDR r2,[r1],#4
 ADD r3,r3,r2
 SUBS r5,r5,#1     
 BNE loop

 data_values
 ALIGN 4
 DCD 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ; example values
 END
```

Comment: Not sure about your assembler, but: 1) what would happen if `data_values` is not aligned? If it works in similar way as other assemblers, that `data_values` symbol will have the unaligned address value, while the `DCD` will define data on aligned one, so your code will do unaligned access to wrong bytes of data. I believe you should swap those two, align first, then define symbolic label. 2) what happens after `BNE`? Or are you just running this in debugger up to that point, never letting it go outside of your defined code?

Comment: Okay thank you, will swap them now. Using Keil tools.
I am just running it to BNE within a debugger as it is just a learning exercise, do you have any recommendations for how to achieve what I have asked for above?

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering whether there is a better way of doing this?

Opinion based... and too broad. There are many ways how you can structure your data, each of them may suit you under different situation. I will try to list all the major ones (I bet I will forget some).

Compile time:

- what you did
- define not only label at beginning of data, but also at end of data, then from their difference you can calculate length in bytes (if assembler doesn't support basic expression, this may require runtime calculation).
- Many assemblers support basic expressions, where instead of defining the end label you can actually do something like `num equ (($ - start_label)/4)` where `$` is current address in some assemblers (probably not with yours, this is x86 TASM/MASM example).
- element and array size is completely fixed forever (ie. "set of 15 strings, each 5 characters long" => 75 bytes exactly and code written to support only that - probably not very usable in real world, except some hw-limited corner cases .. or fast mash-up of learning exercise with focus on something different, where fixed array doesn't matter).

Runtime:

- write code in such way, that caller of function must support not only address of array, but also it's size (very versatile API style, you can usually bend any other structure of data to be processed by such API, although with value-terminated arrays it may be not optimally efficient, as you have to calculate size first) - this delegates the problem of structure to the caller, doesn't solve it on its own.
- use some value as terminator, like ASCII**Z** strings end with value `0`.
- use some structure of data, like C++ `std::vector`, where the internal data structure contains not only pointer to memory, but also separate variable to store size of vector (plus several other variables keeping around capacity of allocated memory and size of last allocation, etc.. check any `std::vector` implementation to get the idea), in your case you may go for example for the simplest `DCD 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1` (first word is size, then data follow).
- anything else you can think of.. some of real world examples are various interleaved structures, like separated bit-planes in old EGA 16 colour graphics modes, where one bank of memory was storing one bit per pixel, and to draw a single pixel you had to switch through all four memory banks, writing into each particular bit value. You can pretty much create anything, what you can sufficiently Mathematically define and write code for it.